# dnsmasq DHCP server on Mac OS - not working

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, dhcp, dnsmasq, macos-ventura

I'm trying to set up a DHCP server using `dnsmasq` on Mac OS (Ventura) so that it can serve IP addresses to virtual machines that I am running.

I have included this line into my `/opt/homebrew/etc/dnsmasq.conf`:

```
dhcp-range=192.168.1.2,192.168.1.100,255.255.255.0,12h
```

and restarted the service using

```
sudo brew services restart dnsmasq
```

I have also disabled the built-in Mac OS DHCP server so that it does not interfere with `dnsmasq`:

```
sudo /bin/launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/bootps.plist
```

I'm running a Linux VM using QEMU, with the following network configuration:

```
-nic vmnet-shared,start-address=192.168.1.1,end-address=192.168.1.254,subnet-mask=255.255.255.0,mac=52:52:52:00:00:00
```

Unfortunately, the DHCP server is silent when I try to contact it from the VM:

```
$ sudo dhclient -v
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.4.1
Copyright 2004-2018 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/enp0s1/52:52:52:00:00:00
Sending on   LPF/enp0s1/52:52:52:00:00:00
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.1.4 on enp0s1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x74f39476)
DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.1.4 on enp0s1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x74f39476)
```

It seems like there's nothing listening on the DHCP port (67) - the `sudo lsof -i4UDP:67` lists nothing.

If I use the built-in Mac OS DHCP server, everything works fine. The VM is getting an IP address and the system shows that something is listening on DHCP port:

```
$ sudo lsof -i4UDP:67
COMMAND PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
launchd   1 root   14u  IPv4 0x6ff053dbd93d2625      0t0  UDP *:bootps
launchd   1 root   22u  IPv4 0x6ff053dbd93d2625      0t0  UDP *:bootps
```

How to make `dnsmasq` work as a DHCP server?

Comment: What is the rest of your `dnsmasq.conf`? You may need to specify `bind-interfaces`, `dhcp-authoritative`, etc. Is dnsmasq logging bind errors somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the cause.

`dnsmasq` binds both as a DHCP and DNS server, and I did not disable the DNS server (because I was planning to configure it later).

When I run the VM, Mac OS starts its own DNS, to serve the VM. If I try to start/restart `dnsmasq` after that point, it will fail to bind the DNS port and won't start. Unfortunately, I did not notice that because `homebrew` **outright lies to me** regarding the status of `dnsmasq` service, saying:

```
==> Successfully started `dnsmasq` (label: homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq)
```

This is false. When I look at `sudo brew services list` (note: `dnsmasq` requires `sudo`), I see:

```
dnsmasq           error  512 root /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq.plist
```

Also, there don't seem to be any logs from `dnsmasq` anywhere so I can't see what the problem is until I try to run `dnsmasq` manually:

```
sudo dnsmasq --no-daemon --log-queries
```

Only then I actually get some message that points me to the problem.

So, summarizing, I got royally confused mostly because of these two factors:

- misleading `homebrew` messages
- the situation depending on whether the VM is currently running or not